# Rust: Why does adding type information prevent a move?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

```rust
fn main() {
    let a = &mut 1;
    let b: &mut i32 = a;
    // let b = a;
    a;
}
```

The above works, but switching out `let b` line for the commented-out line below produces the following error:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `a`
 --> src/junk.rs:5:5
  |
2 |     let a = &mut 1;
  |         - move occurs because `a` has type `&mut i32`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
3 |     // let b: &mut i32 = a;
4 |     let b = a;
  |             - value moved here
5 |     a;
  |     ^ value used here after move
```

My questions are:

1. What are the semantic differences between the two versions?
2. Is there a difference in types between `b` in the two versions?

Comment: When the target type is already known to be a mutable reference, the compiler will implicitly reborrow the mutable reference, i.e. the assignment is equivalent to `let b: &mut i32 = &mut *a;`. This is a frequent question – I'll look up a duplicate with a detailed answer for you.

Comment: Thanks so much @SvenMarnach for finding the duplicate and helping me with further keywords to learn more, much appreciated!